# kernel of linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A \neq 0$ and $\Phi_{A} \, : \, \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ such that : $\forall M \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}), \, \Phi_{A}(M) = {}^t A M A$. (here, ${}^t A$ denotes the transpose of $A$). Can we describe $\mathrm{ker}(\Phi_{A})$ ?

I know that $\Phi_{A}$ is a non-zero linear form on $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. So $\mathrm{dim} \; \mathrm{ker}(\Phi_{A}) = n^{2}-1$. And $\ker(\Phi_{A}) = \left\{ M = (m_{i,j}) \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}), \, \sum \limits_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} m_{i,j}a_{i}a_{j} = 0 \right\}$. Is there anything more clever to say about $\ker(\Phi_{A})$ ? Even when $n=2$, I don't find any other expression for $\ker(\Phi_{A})$.

I apologize if this question has already been asked on MSE. This is not a homework question.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. $\Phi_{A}$ IS a linear form.

Comment: I think you said it all: $\;\ker\Phi_A\;$ is a hyperplane (proper linear subspace of maximal dimension) of $\;\mathcal M_n*\Bbb R)\;$...because $\;\Phi_A\;$ is *in fact* a non-zero linear functional on $\;\mathcal M_a(\Bbb R)\;$